# understanding notation of convergence in hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

In Dirk Werner's *Functional Analysis*, you can find this statement (Theorem V.4.9)

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with ONB $S$. Since $S$ is an ONB, we can write 
$$
f=\sum_{e\in S}(f,e)_{H}e\quad\forall f\in H. 
$$
Can someone explain in one or two sentences what kind of convergence this is? I've read about so many types of convergence. The notation is quite confusing.

Comment: It's convergence in the norm induced by the scalar product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence is in norm. That is, the partial sums of the right-hand side converge to $f$ in the norm on $H$.

Comment: so you can say:  For every $f\in H$ the sum converges in norm $\Vert \cdot\Vert_H$ ?

Comment: Sure. In particular, it converges to $f$ in the $H$-norm.